# UITableViewCell dynamic height + hidden elements take up space in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This is the scenario: I have a Table in which there are Cells with dynamic height. In each cell I have a label and a switch. When I run the App only these two can be seen but then I set the switch to true then a (hidden?) textview appears under these two elements making the height of the cell bigger.

How can I do this? Because when I try hidden elements take up place as well.

This is what I want:
[image]

Reality:
[image]

How can I do this?
I tried using the new Stack View which can handle it fine, BUT NOT in a table cell....

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it mixing this answer: [Dynamic Height Issue for UITableView Cells (Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494702/dynamic-height-issue-for-uitableview-cells-swift) for the dynamic height and then for the views that show or not I added a height constraint to the view and then on cellForRowAtIndexPath just set the constant of the constraint to 0 if you need to hide it or to your height if you show it.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be solved using constraints:
 - set the height constraint for your text view,
 - create the outlet for that constraint in your view controller,
 
 - change the constant property of the constraint in your view controller when the switch is used.

Comment: No. You can change the constraint in a sent action IBAction method of your switch.

Comment: You have to recalculate somehow the height of the cell, it's not going to resize it for you automatically.

Comment: You don't need to calculate at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you hide your text view, your text view is still there, text length is as long as it is not hidden.

So instead of hide/show the text of the text view, you'd better to update the text of your text view from "" -> "what ever you want to show."

In this case, the auto layout can handle your query fair easily. You only need the set

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 65 //whatever number
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

and in the cell xib/storyboard, add constraints on the`top` and`bottom` of your text view, don't also forget to make your text view not scrollable as well.

Actually, I recommend you to simply use`UILabel` in stead of`UITextField`, you just need to set the`lineNumber` of the`Label` to be `0`, and you can neglect the `scroll and size setting` of the text view.

Comment: I need textview because user can write a comment. So I need to show an empty textview.

Comment: Yep. You can show an empty textview and just need to make the textview not scrollable and having proper size as you wanted.

Comment: But I think you are missing out the point that I have to recalculate the height of the row each time.