# Automatic height for static cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have table view with static cell and try set up it to automatic height of cell.

[image]

When I add last vertical constrain between bottom label and bottom border of cell I get bunch of errors. How can I fix this?

Previous similar question was about dynamic cell, I ask about static

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494702/dynamic-height-issue-for-uitableview-cells-swift

Comment: remove height constraints and follow above link'

Comment: It's a little different question then that which was marked as duplicate. Author has static `UITableViewController`, so just setting `estimatedRowHeight` will not help him, also from context I can say that he has problems with `auto layout` which could be solved by setting  `Content Hugging Priority` and `Compression Resistance Priority` for labels

Comment: Add top, bottom, trailing and leading constraints. Later change the vertical hugging priority. Maximum the vertical hugging priority states that the content doesn't want to grow.

Comment: Yeah, change hugging priority actually help. Thanks everyone