# How to set automatic height in heighForRowAt indexPath?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimage, height

I am tried counting the number to make UIImage perfect size each time, so I am making the comic app, and I can upload without a set number to make perfect like that.

I try to import IMG in which UIImage from comicsCell (UITableViewCell) by the Storyboard used.
here i am trying to research for almost 2 weeks and nothing to find a trick way to automatically UIImage Height.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return Int(comicsCells.IMG.bounds.height)
        // error: Cannot find 'comicsCells' in scope
    }
```

Let me know if you find any code to allow me to import the image with automatic height itself.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the automaticDimension like that:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

**PS: Top and bottom constraints is required for this to work.**

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494702/dynamic-height-issue-for-uitableview-cells-swift) post.

Comment: Nice one! But I don't like give me a lot of work to do top and below or do number like that. I have seen some comic app just import to app and it automatically prefect height when upload not matter height number like that. I was hard to think like that.